# how to decode and encode base64 image without losing the quality and the size

Tags: php, android, base64, size, decode

Am encoding an image from android to base64 with this code:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, stream); //compress to which format you want.
            byte [] byte_arr = stream.toByteArray();
            image_str = Base64.encodeToString(byte_arr, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

and than insert it into mysql data base, than decode it with php using that code:

```
$filename_path = md5(time().uniqid()).".jpeg"; 
$decoded=base64_decode($image_str);
 file_put_contents("uploads/".$filename_path,$decoded);
//echo '<img src="uploads/".$filename_path"/>';
echo '<img src="uploads/'.$filename_path.'"/>';
```

it's working all fine i can see the picture and there is no errors, but  the problem is am losing like about 80% of the quality and the size , how can i fix that please.

Comment: It shouldn't affect the image quality. I'd look into this `bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, stream);` - I'm guessing `90` there is a quality setting. Try adjusting it to 100 and turn it down depending on what quality / file size is acceptable to you.

Comment: don't compress the image

Comment: Stick with the original `png` format which uses a lossless compression. The moment you use a `jpg` compression, you lose quality.

Comment: i changed it to 100 but the picture has the same quality and size

Comment: "am losing 80% of the quality and the size" -- please edit your question and provide the code where you are getting this `Bitmap` and doing the comparison to determine your 80% metric.

Comment: it's not an exact aprox, just tryed to show that am losing much quality and size , thanks for you'r advice i edited it .

Comment: `insert it into mysql data base, than decode it with php`. No. Php first decodes the string. After that the image is saved to file system. Not to a database.

Comment: exactly i misexplained , and i found that changing 90 to 100 is the best i cn do , thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

I think if you make the compress format `JPEG`, and reduce the quality of the image to `50`, that should do the trick:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new  ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, baos);
byte [] b = baos.toByteArray();
return Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Comment: If you compress to JPEG format you lose image quality, don't you?

Comment: yes you're right but the losing of quality here is not sensible and the image will be showed with its original quality and size -martijnn2008